# javascript - adding white space to left of string

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a better way to add x amount of white space to a string?

```
str = "blah";
x = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
  str = ' ' + str;
}

return str;
```

Comment: Define 'better.' Incidentally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343844/create-a-string-of-variable-length-filled-with-a-repeated-character

Comment: If performance matters, you're doing a lot of unnecessary string concatenations when x becomes high. Imagine you wanted 512 spaces. Concatenating two strings of 256 spaces would be faster than prepending a space 512 times. On my phone but this is usually called left and right padding of strings.

Comment: no point having a loop if you are always adding the same amount of padding

Comment: There's a "padding function" in *web browsers*.  What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want those spaces?

Comment: you can check it in this question

http://stackoverflow.com/a/202627/2464118

Comment: Have a look at the String.repeat method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: @Pointy I have a <textarea> that enables you to create a json object, each line represents a sequence of objects, depending on how many white spaces are before the first non-white space character of each line determines where it belongs

Comment: OK then, that explains a lot. Carry on :)

Comment: just trying to make the json object easier to read and edit for people with no programming experience, that way I dont have to create a screen for every part of the application, if you know what i mean

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Could do it like this, prevents the loop.

`str = str + new Array(x + 1).join(' ')`

Comment: This gives a length of `x - 1` because join takes the element at right and the last element does not have one. So it should be `new Array(x + 1).join(' ')`

Comment: Also, it should be `str = new Array(x+1).join(' ') + str;`. Your version pads on the wrong side.

Comment: Durp, you are correct this pads to the right. I didn't read the question properly. Guess its to late in the night for me.

Comment: it is all good, i figured out to put it on the other side, just waiting for time to run out to give answer

Comment: Yeah definitely, I just pointed it out since @aduch also pointed something out. Very elegant solution by the way.

Comment: Doesnt work, <td> collapses all the white spaces, any better methods to insert whitespace?

Answer (score 26):

In ES6 you can do the following:

```
str = ' '.repeat(x) + str;
```

At this point in time (late 2014) it's only available in Chrome and Firefox. But in two years it should be widely supported.

See the documentation for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively using lodash [`_.padStart`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#padStart). Pads string on the left side if it's shorter than length.

```js
const str = 'blah',
  len = str.length,
  space = 4;
console.log(_.padStart(str, len + space));
// => '    blah'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or pure [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
const str = 'blah',
  len = str.length,
  space = 4;
console.log(str.padStart(len + space, ' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

for example you can use repeat for the white space left or right of your string:

```
var j = 6;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(" ".repeat(j-1)+"#".repeat(i+1))
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padStart` and `padEnd` methods.
For eg.:

```js
const str1 = 'Hello';
const str2 = 'World';
const str3 = str1.padEnd(2,' ')+str2.padStart(1,' ');
console.log(str3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = 'stack' + Array(6).fill('\xa0').join('') + 'overflow'
console.log(message);
```

```js
var message = 'stack' + Array(6).fill('\xa0').join('') + 'overflow'
console.log(message);
```