# Mock the length of a string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine

I am trying to test (with Jasmine) validation of a description field (which is a knockout observable) with max length of 1000 characters;
What I usually do is `expect(model.description().length).toBe(1000);` 
to prove that my string is of the desired length.
Is there any way to mock it somehow without the need to actually write a string of 1000 chars long?

Comment: you could use `Array(1001).join("a")`

Comment: Thank you, if no other way, then I will use it :)

Comment: What is the purpose of checking the length of a string that is generated just to pass the test?

Comment: You can monkey patch `model.description` and put a mock of an observable in there that has a settable `length` property. But this feels like an XY-problem to me :-)

Comment: @GOTO0 There isn't, I just used it here to explain what I mean.

Comment: In that case, something like `".".repeat(1000)` will do it, or even just `{ length: 1000 }` if you're only interested in the length property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intent on mocking the object and just want to use the `length` property and nothing else then as mentioned by @GOTO-0, you can just create an object with that property set like this: `{ length: 1000 }`.

However, it seems easier to just create a string that is that length. This could help as if some of the code changes to require an actual string elsewhere, the test will still be valid rather than you having to start mocking other methods and properties of a string. See this question for discussions on how to do that best: [Create a string of variable length, filled with a repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343844/create-a-string-of-variable-length-filled-with-a-repeated-character)