# Manipulating a String's content with an Integer

Tags: javascript, string, loops, multiplication

I'f you're familiar with Python, I'm sure you're aware that you can multiply a String by an Integer to get that desired amount of Strings back.

---

Example:

```
'J' * 3 --> 'JJJ'
```

---

What's the most efficient way to do this in JavaScript?

I was looking for an inline method; similar to that of Pythons behaviour

---

A few of my ideas:

```
var str = 'J',
    strOld = str,
    timesToExtend = 3;

for(var i = 0; i < timesToExtend; i++){
    str += strOld;
}

= 'JJJ'
```

---

```
var str = 'J',
    timesToExtend = 5,
    strOld = str;

while(!timesToExtend){
  str += strOld;
  timesToExtend--;
}
```

---

These are just rough ideas, so don't expect them to be 100% accurate and working. I assume this **MUST** contain a loop; however any method without a loop will be praised!

Thanks for reading; thank you for your response in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343844/create-a-string-of-variable-length-filled-with-a-repeated-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES6 you can use [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and then join the array:

```
Array(3).fill('J').join('');
```

Comment: Will this work in Node.JS?

Comment: @Robinlemon it works from node 4.4.5